# How to access Nintex managed holidays in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

We are building a pretty straight forward business project that uses SharePoint 2010 and Nintex workflows. Just the usual lists with workflows attached doing stuff to the list items.

Nintex workflows can do pauses for X number of days that *exclude* holidays if the holiday dates are entered through the Nintex "Manage Holidays" action in the settings for a web. It just lets you enter a bunch of Name + Date combinations. That's great and lets the workflows do their job nicely.

Now, we'd like to be able to do custom calculations in a web service that a Nintex workflow can call, that also take those holidays into account. The calculations are just too complex to do with the features that Nintex gives you - which is fine.

My question is; is there some way to query that list of dates that we have entered for Nintex to use? They're not stored in any SharePoint lists, hidden or otherwise; they go straight into the Nintex database. I have looked at the Nintex workflow webservice - all the functions seem to be specific to starting/stopping workflows etc.

I'd also rather avoid accessing the Nintex database directly, or duplicate those dates in a SharePoint list.

Is there any way to get at that data? Either through .NET code (using the nintex dlls) or other webservices?

Cheers :D

Cheers

Comment: I'd also like to point out that Nintex is surfacing that info in a SharePoint page so it must be possible... but I don't know how it's getting at that data....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are public property and method to get holidays in Nintex.Workflow.dll:

```
public class HolidayCollection : List<Holiday>
{

    // all holidays
    public static HolidayCollection Holidays { get; }

    // holidays specific to current web
    public HolidayCollection GetHolidays(Guid webId, Guid siteId);

}
```

Declaring Type: Nintex.Workflow.Scheduling.HolidayCollection

Assembly: Nintex.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow thank you! Never thought I'd ever get a reply to this. ;)

Comment: Do you accept this as answer? If so, please indicate it explicitly :)

Comment: Well, I have since moved on, so I cant test it. Happy to mark as the answer though.